# How can I change my Mac address permanently!?

Tags: hardware, nic

I am new to Linux platform. I need to change mac address permanently. I tried various methods. Everything thing works on VMware. But not on my Ubuntu system. Did anyone tried to change and succeed!??

Comment: What MAC address? You mean the MAC of your network card?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether 00:00:00:00:00:00
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

Where eth0 is your network interface and 00:00:00:00:00:00 is your desire MAC addres.

If you want to save this changes when rebooting you have to add this to /etc/network/interfaces

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
 hwaddress ether 08:00:00:00:00:00
```

Source: [How to change the MAC address of an Ethernet interface](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2013/01/11/how-to-change-the-mac-address-of-an-ethernet-interface/)

Comment: I tried but facing the error.SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted